# Telerik:Radgrid Unable to get items in Insert/Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a problem, when I defined the radgrid:

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="Radgrid" runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight"
                                                OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid_NeedDataSource"
                                                OnColumnCreated="RadGrid_ColumnCreated"
                                                OnItemCreated="RadGrid_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid_ItemDataBound"
                                                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true"
                                                AllowSorting="true" 
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditColumn="false" OnInsertCommand="Radgrid_InsertCommand">
                                                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
                                                <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Bottom" CommandItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
                                                    EditMode="EditForms" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" EditFormSettings-EditColumn-AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                                                
                                                    <Columns>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CodEnte" HeaderText="CODICE ENTE" UniqueName="CodEnte" AllowFiltering="true" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="RagioneSociale" HeaderText="RAGIONE SOCIALE" UniqueName="RagioneSociale" AllowFiltering="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PartitaIva" HeaderText="PARTITA IVA" UniqueName="PartitaIva" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Pec" HeaderText="PEC" UniqueName="Pec" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="EMAIL" UniqueName="Email" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Via" HeaderText="INDIRIZZO" UniqueName="Via" AllowSorting="false" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comune" HeaderText="COMUNE" UniqueName="Comune" AllowSorting="false" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Provincia" HeaderText="PROVINCIA" UniqueName="Provincia" AllowSorting="false" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Cap" HeaderText="CAP" UniqueName="Cap" AllowSorting="false" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" EditText="Modifica">
                                                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                                                    </Columns>    
                                                        
                                                    <CommandItemSettings
                                                        ShowRefreshButton="false" ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" />
                                                    <EditFormSettings EditFormType ="Template" EditColumn-AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" EditColumn-ButtonType="FontIconButton">
                                                        <FormTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Cod Ente:" Width="120px" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextCodEnte" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Cod Ente" Visible="true"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextCodEnte" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Ragione Sociale:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextRagioneSociale" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Ragione Sociale"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextRagioneSociale" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Partita Iva:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextPartitaIva" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Partita Iva"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="PEC:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextPEC" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="PEC"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextPEC" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Email:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextEmail" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Email"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Via:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextVia" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Via"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextVia" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Comune:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextComune" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Comune"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextComune" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Provincia:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextProvincia" Width="50px" EmptyMessage="Provincia"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextProvincia" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="CAP:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                                                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="TextCap" Width="100px" EmptyMessage="CAP"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextCap" ErrorMessage="!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <br />
                                                            <telerik:RadButton  runat="server" ID="linkInserisci" Width="50px" Text="Inserisci" CommandName="PerformInsert" /> 
                                                            <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="linkCancel" Width="50px" Text="Annulla" CommandName="Cancel" OnClick="linkCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false"/> 
                                                            <br />
                                                        </FormTemplate>
                                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                                </MasterTableView>
                                            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

In front-end I see this:

[image]

When I click INSERISCI button, that you can find into the FormTemplate, I need to run some server code to insert values into textbox. This is my method:

```
protected void Radgrid_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = Radgrid;
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.PerformInsertCommandName)
        {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            var dataItem = item.DataItem;
        }
    }
```

but the dataItem is null. I need the text values into the FormTemplate to Serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified in your code as per below for different Edit mode, Which I have used in my project. Hope it works for you.

However, Telerik Radgrid is a very powerful grid which provides most of the functionality Out of the Box.

You can explore more from:[Telerik Embedded mode reference](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx)

```
  protected void Radgrid_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) {
  var control = Radgrid;
  //As Radgrid_InsertCommand is anly used called when insert command performed below condition may be not required

  if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.PerformInsertCommandName) {

   if (Radgrid.MasterTableView.EditMode == GridEditMode.PopUp || Radgrid.MasterTableView.EditMode == GridEditMode.EditForms) {
    // Get inserted item data in popup and embedded  edit mode
    GridEditableItem ei = ((GridEditableItem)(e.Item));
   } else if (Radgrid.MasterTableView.EditMode == GridEditMode.InPlace) {
    // Get inserted item data in inline edit mode
    GridDataInsertItem ei = (GridDataInsertItem) e.Item.OwnerTableView.GetInsertItem();

   }
  }
 }
```